# Error while storing objects in local storage

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I've got an error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': Position object could not be cloned.
>   Error: Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': Position object could not be cloned.

Here's a code:

```
geolocate() {
    this.geo.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
      // resp.coords.latitude
      // resp.coords.longitude
      this.storage.set('GeoLocation', resp);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error getting location', error);
    });

    let watch = this.geo.watchPosition();
    watch.subscribe((data) => {

      // data can be a set of coordinates, or an error (if an error occurred).
      // data.coords.latitude
      // data.coords.longitude
    });
  }
```

Comment: What is the type of response? does it contain any function? You can try serializing the resp object before storing it.

Comment: @Tanmay_vijay: i've just used: this.storage.set('GeoLocation', resp);  to store in localstorage and that contains that error. How to solve it ?

Comment: Can you try this.storage.set('GeoLocation', JSON.stringify(resp));

Comment: @Tanmay_vijay: i've got an empty array in local storage.

Comment: Try my answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
geolocate() {
    this.geo.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
      // resp.coords.latitude
      // resp.coords.longitude
      const location = {latitude: resp.coords.latitude, longitude: resp.coords.longitude};
      this.storage.set('GeoLocation', JSON.stringify(location));
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error getting location', error);
    });

    let watch = this.geo.watchPosition();
    watch.subscribe((data) => {

      // data can be a set of coordinates, or an error (if an error occurred).
      // data.coords.latitude
      // data.coords.longitude
    });
  }
```

And for reading it back use `JSON.parse` as follows:

```
JSON.parse(this.storage.get('GeoLocation'));
```

Comment: its ok, but i've got this kind of format in ls: "{"latitude":44.754405999999996,"longitude":19.2232672}" thats not right format. I dont need {} in my LocalStorage

Comment: It's easier to read back this way. I'm not sure why you don't want {}. You can try storing them separately as well. `this.storage.set('latitude', resp.coords.latitude)` and same for longititude.